# when I read message I am getting extra info. How to avoid that

Tags: json, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, pubnub

I am able to read message from `Pub nub` but I only want "Yes" or "No". I am getting `{u'text':'Yes'}` and `{u'text':'No'}`. How to avoid extra things?

Here is my code:

```
while True:                                             
    result = my_listener.wait_for_message_on(channel)      
    print(result.message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:                                             
    result = my_listener.wait_for_message_on(channel)      
    print(result.message.get('text'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much... it was trying to get ans whole yesterday and finally you helped. it's working :)